# React Router: Advantages/disadvantages of route structure

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This has been on the back of my mind for while now. I was wondering if anyone had some insights.

Here are two examples:

```
<Route path="/" component={Container}>
    <Route path="user" component={Users}>
        <Route path="user/:id" component={Profile} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

In the above example my *Users* component would be rendering the *Profile* component through `props.children`.

```
<Route path="/" component={Container}>
    <Route path="user" component={Users} />
    <Route path="user/:id" component={Profile} />
</Route>
```

This example would be essentially the same as the first except I would need to import the *Users* component in Profile.

**Is there any advantages/disadvantages to each approach in terms of performance and/or architecture?**

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is very unlikely to be a cause any performance concerns, the two options are just organized differently and will behave differently. There isn't a better choice--only a choice that makes the most sense for your app.

The most important thing to keep in mind is that `children` is just a prop. Changing props doesn't cause your component to unmount. However, new `children` will cause the previous `children` to unmount.

In your first example, if you navigate to `user/1` and then later navigate to `user/5`, `Profile` component will have mounted once, then unmounted, then mounted again.. but `Users` will have only mounted once.

If you do the same thing in your second example, `Users` and `Profile` will mount---then both unmount and mount again. This is because in this scenario the `children` that are changing, are those of `Container`.

Without any other information about your app.. it seems that the first scenario is more desirable because fewer components mount / unmount.. perhaps you can retain some state that way, but then again it depends on what your app needs to do.

Comment: thanks for the insights. Good observation about mounting/unmounting